# What would be the best way to index and search my data using Lucene?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, faceted-search

I’ve found multiple questions on SO and elsewhere that ask questions along the lines of “How can I index and then search relational data in Lucene”. Quite rightly these questions are met with the standard response that Lucene is not designed to model data like this. This quote I found sums it up…

> A Lucene Index is a Document Store. In a Document Store, a single
>   document represents a single concept with all necessary data stored to
>   represent that concept (compared to that same concept being spread
>   across multiple tables in an RDBMS requiring several joins to
>   re-create).

So I will not ask that question and instead provide my high level requirements and see if any Lucene gurus out there can help me.

- We have data on People (Name, Gender, DOB, Nationality, etc)
- And data on Companies (Name, Country, City, etc).
- We also have data about how these two types of entity relate to each other where a person worked at the company (Person, Company, Role, Date Started, Date Ended, etc).

We have two entities – Person and Company – that have their own properties and then properties exist for the many-to-many link between them.

Some example searches could be as follows…

- Find all Companies in Australia
- Find all People born between two dates
- Find all People who have worked as a .Net Developer
- Find all males who have worked as a.Net Developer in London.
- Find all People who have worked as a .Net Developer between 2008 and 2010

The criteria span all the three sets of data. Our requirement is to provide a [Faceted Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search) over the data that accepts any combination of the various properties, of which I have given some examples.

I would like to use [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for this. We are a .Net software house and so feel slightly intimidated by java. However, all suggestions are welcome.

I am aware of the idea that the Index should be constructed with the search in mind. But I can’t seem to come up with a sensible index that would meet all the combinations of search criteria

- What classes native to Lucene or what extension points can we make use of.
- Are there are established techniques for doing this kind of thing?
- Are there any third open source contributions that I have missed that will help us here?

For now I won’t describe the scenarios we have considered because I don’t want to bloat out this question and make it too intimidating. Please ask me to elaborate where necessary.

Comment: I don't think that Lucene.Net(or any other text search engine) is very suitable for your needs. Maybe you should go with `embedded databases`

Comment: Consider asking this on the Lucene-net-user@a.o mailing list

Comment: I second @Prescott's suggestion. It's a friendly list and they're willing to help out if you provide good enough info (which you did here). 1 suggestion (don't have much time now) you state: "But I can’t seem to come up with a sensible index that would meet all the combinations of search criteria".. That really isn't necessary. If you can't get it to work with 1 conceptual document-type.. (e.g: people with flattened companies) use 2 (companies with flattend people), etc.. (overly simplified btw).  I have zero knowledge on the .Net port. If I were you, I'd omit that in the question to the list

Comment: Continued: just to get the best possible solutions going. Afterwards you can always check if it's supported in the .net variant. (or you might end up running the java-variant as a standalone server just communicating over http from .net if that's within spec.)

Comment: Many thanks for the mailing list suggestion. I have asked on there too.

Answer (score 2):

To store both companies and people in a single index, you could create documents with a `type` field that identifies the type of entities they describe.

Birthdays can be stored as date fields.

You could give each person a simple text field containing the names of companies that they worked for. Note that you won't get an error if you enter a company that is not represented by a document in your index. Lucene is not a relational DB tool, but you knew that.

(Sorry that I've not posted any links to the API; I'm familiar with Lucene Core but not Lucene.NET.)

Comment: Thanks @larsmans. We have actually considered this kind of index structure but I wonder if you can help me with the question of how I interpret the results. I'll update my question...

Comment: Actually, before I do that. How to you see the Roles being stored along side the Companies, which are already part of the Person document? Each company/Role pair would have to be separate so a match on both could be identified properly - and then there is of course the Start/End date of the role. Do you think a third Document type of "Role" would be required, and if so, how would we "link" them together?

Comment: an option would be that each company/Role pair is actually modeled as a single value. [company X role] -> int for example. Store this in a multivalued field. Have your client know how to encode/ decode it, etc. Don't have an answer for the start/end per role at the moment. Perhaps it would help to specify the queries that you are likely to encounter that include these role x start/end date combos

Comment: Thanks Geert-Jan. I take you suggestion of a Company/Role multivalued field on board, but I can't seem to get my head around how I would query this in conjunction with the multiple conceptual document types. Are you suggesting that the query would return documents of both types and then I would have to post process them to filter the ones I want. I go back to the example of finding "All People who have worked as a .Net Dev in London". .Net Dev would be part of the Person document type and London would be part of the Company document type. Could I create a query to return only Person documents?